# How to urlencode multi valued keys in python?

Tags: python, urlencode

I want to do this in python:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/samos/select?rows=0&q=*:*&fq=time:\[2012-08-01T00:00:00Z%20TO%202013-10-01T00:00:00Z\]&fq=loc:\[15,-45%20TO%2030,-30\]'
```

So I made a dictionary and tried the request:

```
webpage = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/samos/select'
query_args = {
    'q' : '*:*', \
    'fq' : ['time:[2012-08-01T00:00:00Z TO 2013-10-01T00:00:00Z]', \
    'fq' : 'loc:[15,-45 TO 30,-30]', \
    'rows' : '0' \
}
query = urllib.urlencode(query_args)
req = urllib2.Request(webpage, query)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

The problem here is I have two values for my 'fq' key, so only one argument is being processed. What is the easiest way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) will accept a sequence that yields 2-tuples.

> Convert a mapping object *or* a **sequence of two-element tuples** to a “percent-encoded” string. ...

e.g.

```
query_args = [
    ('q', '*:*'),
    ('fq', 'time:[2012-08-01T00:00:00Z TO 2013-10-01T00:00:00Z]'),
    ('fq', 'loc:[15,-45 TO 30,-30]'),
    ('rows', '0'),
]
```

Demo:

```
>>> urllib.urlencode(query_args)
'q=%2A%3A%2A&fq=time%3A%5B2012-08-01T00%3A00%3A00Z+TO+2013-10-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%5D&fq=loc%3A%5B15%2C-45+TO+30%2C-30%5D&rows=0'
```

Note, this is also what you want to use if for some reason the *order* of the query parameters matters.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.